# How to hide or encrypt the payloads when API calling is made from js of LWC?

Tags: rest, client, salesforce-lightning, lwc

When the API is invoked, you can observe the `this.accessToken` and the request body in the browser's network tab.

```
const response = fetch(endpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.accessToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ contentVersionIds: contentVersionId }),
    timeout: 1200000, // 12 seconds timeout
})
```

To enhance security, is it possible to conceal or encrypt the payloads transmitted during API calls?

Comment: SSL is the recommended security layer that will protect you using HTTPS encrypting the data in transit. However you can manually encript the payload if you want to over engineer - 
const encryptedPayload = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify({ contentVersionIds: contentVersionId }), 'secretKey').toString();

Comment: Thanks @RicardoGellman 
Salesforce is a secure platform and we have SSL too. This CryptoJS is a library of node js but I want to use it in js of the LWC component. Can you please provide me with an example of this?